# Matplotlib more precise python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that stores the salary for each employee. Here is an example:

```
    EMPLOYEE_CODE   SALARY
0   PR3016      470.40
1   CH3028      499.46
2   MY0137      389.64
3   519109      589.33
4   AG1031      884.90

        SALARY
count       25330.000000
mean        541.827661
std     856.875652
min     0.000000
25%     250.255000
50%     362.900000
75%     550.617500
max     40842.090000
```

To visualize this data, I wanted to plot a histogram like this:

```
df_user.SALARY.plot.hist()
```

But I got a not very precise plot.

[image]

Any idea to have more precise plot?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using pandas, use the [number of bins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) to control this, e.g. `df_user.SALARY.plot.hist(bins=100)`

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what library you are using, and what you mean by precise.  If matplotlib, the doc for `hist` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html
says you can use the parameter `bins=n`, where `n`is the number of bins you want.